# Using the sentence sorry to hear that

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, usage, american-english

I have noticed many times like if a person says to someone that one of my relative passed
away the other person replies **Sorry to hear that** 
I don't get the meaning of this reply. Sorry is used for forgiveness or when someone has done
a mistake and he promises not to do it again. Is this a correct sentence ? 
Is there any better reply than this?

Answer (score 5):

"Sorry" is mostly used as an apology now. But it has a wider meaning that is more common in the related<sup>*</sup> word "sorrow". "Sorry" means "full of sorrow".

As an apology, it literally says "I am full of sorrow for doing something wrong".  But it can still mean "full of sorrow" in other contexts.

If you are told that someone has died, it is natural and normal to say "I'm sorry to hear that" meaning "I am full of sorrow to hear that the person has died".

<sub>* related, but not cognate.  The OE word was "sarig" with the change from "a" to "o" influenced by the word "sorg" which had a similar meaning and coincidental similar sound.  *Sarig* and *sorg* became "sorry" and "sorrow" repectively.</sub>

Comment: Thanks that make sense. But on the other hand it's like has become a standard reply. I mean like if I don't know someone I am not actually full of sorrow. But still it seems polite to reply that.

Comment: Yes, it is a standard, conventional and polite reply.

Comment: You can say 'I'm sorry to hear that you have been unwell' and it is heard as an expression of kind concern.

Comment: You are probably not literally 'full of sorrow', but you feel regret that the other person has had bad news.

Comment: Government employees got an email saying that it was understood how everybody must be feeling 'the most profound and utter regret' at the death of Prince Philip, but that they must carry on in spite of that.

Answer (score 3):

The act of **being** (or **feeling**) **sorry** about something has two different connotations:

- You caused the issue/situation, and are apologizing for it: you feel bad because it was your fault.
- You did not cause the issue, but you still feel bad about it because you empathize with the other person and you wish they weren't sad about it.

Saying **I'm sorry to hear that** is an example of the second meaning, and is very commonly used in that way. But there can be misunderstandings if the other person thinks, as you did, that "I'm sorry" *only* means the first thing.